# The error that the other server returned was: 550 Mailbox does not exist

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

The problem started suddenly. I have a problem that I can not solve when a random address send email to my domain martizi.com:

[image]

> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   martizi.com by feedback-smtp.us-west-2.amazonses.com.
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 550 Mailbox does not
>   exist!"

I use SES only to send email, just that. I want to be clear about the problem I'm having:

1. Use SES only to send email.
2. I have a corporate email that is provided by another company (here I can not receive the emails)

In my domain I have another MX address that is from the company email. Sometimes when someone tries to send email to some box @ martizi.com, it returns with the error shown above.

I've seen a solution to this problem: Adding email from domains
SES panel> Domains> Mail From Domains> ...
After this he gives me an mx record to put in my domain, I put it, however it stays PENDING VERIFY and after 72 hours, it fails. I've done this twice and it does not check. Is this the solution?

TKS!

Answer (score 0):

Either you are receiving email for martizi.com using SES, or you aren't.

You say that you aren't.  This means you should **not** have this entry in DNS.

```
martizi.com. 3600 IN MX 10 feedback-smtp.us-west-2.amazonses.com.
```

With that entry, you're telling the world that `feedback-smtp.us-west-2.amazonses.com.` is one possible server (of several) that will accept incoming email addressed to martizi.com.  That isn't the case, so the existence of this is a misconfiguration.  Remove this entry.